# I have an increasing bald spot on my character why?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

I started working on a character that I'm planning on using in cycles animation. when I first rendered the character the bald spot wasn't a big problem and now it is. here are two different renders.

[image: render 1]

[image: render 2]

what do I do?

Comment: Wow, Blender is so realistic. It happens to the best of us.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the human is going through hair loss before it's born

Comment: Can you share a blend file with the head and the hair? It's hard to tell. Could be the weights for the density.

Comment: here's the blend file.                https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sq3s-ahp_YCiMg0tJ4NaPbMowRMJEG6t

Comment: @fungaming51 sorry, don't work. The link is private

Comment: here"s the shared link.     https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sq3s-ahp_YCiMg0tJ4NaPbMowRMJEG6t?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated hair particles don't have enough geometry to bend properly and seem to stick into the head because of this.

There are three settings to control this. One is in the *Particle Edit* mode (N-panel, tools options), and the two others that are relevant for you are in the *Particle Properties*

- *Render > Steps*. Set this to `4` or `5`. The value is the power of 2. Don't go crazy. Also, uncheck here `[_]` *Show Emitter* because you don't need to render the hair cap.
- *Viewport Display > Strand Steps*. Use the same value. Default is 2.

In the *Eevee* render settings, set *Hair Shape Type* to `Strip`. This makes the hair in *Eevee* render and *Material Preview* look similar to the hair in Cycles render mode.

Now Jeff's hair is back:

[image: Jeff's hair is back]

Comment: thankyou, blunder